# Re-attaching A Cable To A Circuitboard

Tags: cables, batteries, drone

I have a drone, but one of the cables connecting the battery to the circuit detached and I took it apart so I could have better acces to the circuit board. I know where the cable goes but my problem is I do not know how to reattach it to the circuit board. The cable and the area of attachment are both flat/there are no hoops or anything to tie the conducting of the cable around. I have tried to find a way to do it but I do not want to damage it by doing something I'm not sure will work or will have negative consequences.
Can any of you please help me?

Comment: you could start by posting a picture of the relevant area of the board, and cable end, it saves me having to crank up my ESP!

Comment: 'I do not know how to reattach it to the circuit board.' If you don't know and you can see the thing, how do you expect us to? Photo, man. Photo!

Answer (score 2):

If the cable has some form of flat connector like faston (google it) you can insert the male part in the female part. If there are no connectors, the wire was badly soldered to the board and went broke, so you have to buy a solder iron and (Preferably lead tin alloy for ease of use) solder wire and solder it on again. If you don't have experience contact some tv repairman or radio amateur to get it repaired.